# MongoDB bulk API insert times out

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a nodejs script which usese the mongodb module and the bulk api provided by mongo to do some bulk operations (basically upserts [inserts or updates]).

This works fine, however for larger date I am getting a timeout from the mongdb server. Does anyone know how I can avoid this. I couldn't find anything related to this. PS. Mongo server is up and running, I get the timeout only when the date is larger

```
{ [MongoError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out' }
```

The batch count is only 254